# Im new to Programming and im trying to implement google signin in my app but ive run into an error and im not sure whats wrong

Tags: android, google-signin

This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow so sorry in advance if im doing something wrong.

from previous research it seems the error has to do with a missing curly bracket or something but i cant seem to find the error.

this is my error

```
Error:(61, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(61, 17) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(61, 28) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

the error is at

```
//Start sign in
        private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

and my code is

```
package com.madchallenge2016edwindaniel.upbirdwatchers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;



public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private SignInButton mSignInButton;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



    //Background
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.login_background);

    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new                      GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    signIn();
                    break;
                // ...
            }
        }
    });

//Start sign in
        private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }




}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

Comment: You could at least tel us which line is line 61?

Comment: You can't switch-case on R.id. values. You have to use if-elses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `}` is missing before `private void signIn() {` to close the method `onCreate`.

In order to avoid this kind of typo, **always** indent your code correctly:

```
public void foo() {
    // correct
}

public void foo() {
    // incorrect
    }

    public void foo() {
    // incorrect
}
```